# How to remove large number of rows/data from production MySQL

Tags: mysql

How do I best handle removing data from a table on a production system with 2-3 million rows, each of which has potentially 100k-1M of data (multiple mediumtext fields containing xml) ? Probably around 3/4 of the rows will be removed as they are legacy data which is no longer needed.

I wrote a plsql script that breaks up the deletion into managable chunks per transaction, but there is still the problem with the binlog (the database is replicated) which rapidly fills up, and is only truncated automatically every couple of days IIRC.

My current thinking is just to register some kind of cron task to run daily for each database, removing enough each day to avoid the binlog filling up, and let them get cleared up over time. Are there any better options ?

If all the xml fields for rows which were to be deleted were to be set to null prior to being deleted, would this mean that the size of the binlog would be reduced, compared to just deleting the row immediately ?

Comment: This should be on dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably go about it the way you describe.

Script runs on cron to clear old records in chunks, and if needed you can purge binlogs as required depending on your replication schedule. As per the MySQL docs

> If you are using replication, you should not delete old binary log files on the master until you are sure that no slave still needs to use them. For example, if your slaves never run more than three days behind, once a day you can execute mysqladmin flush-logs on the master and then remove any logs that are more than three days old. You can remove the files manually, but it is preferable to use PURGE BINARY LOGS, which also safely updates the binary log index file for you (and which can take a date argument). See Section 14.4.1.1, “PURGE BINARY LOGS Syntax”.
>   [As per Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-log.html)

Comment: Ended up doing this, it only took two weeks to delete the data. The schedule was loose enough that the binlog had plenty of time to purge itself. 2k entries every 15 minutes across 2 weeks is over 2.5 million - so small batches really do accumulate surprisingly quickly into large amounts of data.

Comment: Removed almost 100 gigs of data from mysql innodb tables doing this btw (multiple instances of similar databases). Remember to run "optimize table" afterwards or it won't reclaim the space from the filesystem - but you need to have innodb_file_per_table set, or you cannot reclaim the space.